# Play sound using flash and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, flash, actionscript

I'll explain my scenario. I want to play a small sound at certain situation, so I would prefer initiating the play via jQuery.

Also, I wish to make a toggle button for the sound. So, the user could turn ON/OFF the sound.
So, I'm thinking about creating the toggle button and function for playing the sound inside the Flash. But I don't how to call this function (that I have written in Actionscript, which will start playing the sound) via jQuery !

Do you have some ideas ?
I haven't done creating the Flash document, but bookmarked some tutorials and will start playing with it soon. :)
The reason for choosing Flash is that it would be crossbrowser compatible.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you prefer to write your own Flash implementation, there is the well proven SoundManager (used by Google and others) for "reliable cross-platform audio under a single JavaScript API": http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö: Hi again, can you please repost it as an answer so that I could mark it as the "ANSWER". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you prefer to write your own Flash implementation, there is the well proven SoundManager 2, for "reliable cross-platform audio under a single JavaScript API":

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/